# About recursive enumeration in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I am learning swift by reading Apple's book **The swift programming language**, I have some questions concerning **Recursive Enumeration**. (I have read the book about it but don't quite understand).

The example code:

```
    enum ArithmeticExpression {
    case Number(Int)
    indirect case Addition(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
    indirect case Multiplication(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
}
```

is said could change to :

```
indirect enum ArithmeticExpression {
    case Number(Int)
    case Addition(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
    case Multiplication(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
}
```

I have three questions:

Q1. Why & what is the purpose of the `indirect` keyword?

Q2. If put `indirect` in front of `enum`, does it mean all the cases after **first** case are recursive cases of the first case?

Q3. In practice, what is the different between the above sample code and the following one (which doesn't have `indirect` keyword):

```
enum ArithmeticExpression {
        case Number(Int)
        case Addition(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
        case Multiplication(ArithmeticExpression, ArithmeticExpression)
    }
```

Comment: Chris Lattner is explaining the indirect keyword in this WWDC talk if I remember correctly: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=106. (However his explanation is not the best.)

Answer (score 1):

The `indirect` keyword is used to tell the compiler, that this `enum` is recursive and it has to treat it indirect (like a class) since value types normally have a fixed memory footprint.

If you write `indirect` before `enum` or the `cases` is not relevant for the compiler. The former one can be used if you have a lot of cases which would have to be marked as `indirect`. So it is a shorter notation and the compiler figures out where to put the keyword.

Your last example doesn't even compile due to the fixed memory footprint I mentioned earlier.